# Accepting Numbers from 1-9 TIC TAC TOE

Tags: python, python-2.7, tic-tac-toe

Here's a TIC TAC TOE game i have created using Python..

```
import os
os.system('cls')

i = 0
#Exiter
def exithoja():
    import sys
    raw_input
    sys.exit()

#Displays Win or Draw
def diswin(name,grid):
    i = checkwin(grid)
    os.system('cls')

    viewgrid(grid)

    if i ==1:
        print name, " has won the game !!"
    elif i == -1:
        print "This Match is a draw !!"
    exithoja()
#Checking for Win or Draw Function
def checkwin(grid):
    i = 0
    result = 0
    extra=0
    for i in range (1,9):            #This part checks for full grid.
        if (grid[i] == 'X' or grid[i]=='O'):
            extra += 1
        if (grid[1] == grid[2] and grid[2] == grid[3]):
            result = 1                   #This part checks for win.

        elif(grid[4] == grid[5] and grid[5] == grid[6]):
            result = 1
        elif(grid[7] == grid[8] and grid[8] == grid[9]):
            result = 1

        elif(grid[1] == grid[4] and grid[4] == grid[7]):
            result = 1

        elif(grid[2] == grid[5] and grid[5] == grid[8]):
            result = 1

        elif(grid[3] == grid[6] and grid[6] == grid[9]):
            result = 1

        elif(grid[1] == grid[5] and grid[5] == grid[9]):
            result = 1

        elif(grid[3] == grid[5] and grid[5] == grid[7]):
            result = 1

        elif(extra==9):       #This part checks for draw.
            result = -1

    return result         #0 for continue,1 for win, -1 for draw.


#Grid Print Function
def viewgrid(grid):
    print "\n\n      .       .\n",
    print "      |       |    "
    for i in range(1,10):
        if i%3==0:
            print " ",
        else:
            print "",
        print "",grid[i]," ",
        if i%3 == 0:
            if i == 9:
                print "\n      |       |",
                print "\n      '       '"
            else:
                print "\n      |       |    ",
                print "\n------+-------+-------\n",
                print "      |       |    "

        else:
            print "|",

#Grid Print Function Ends

#Marks the user choice is possible ('X' or 'O' if possible, 0 if not possible)
def markgrid(user,grid, place):
    if grid[place] != place:
        returnvalue = 0
    else:
        returnvalue = user
    return returnvalue
#End of Mark Grid Function



#Player 1 Marking Function Part 1
def player11(name1,grid):
    while True:
        os.system('cls')
        viewgrid(grid)
        print name1, ", Please enter your choice from the grid above : ",
        place = raw_input()
        try:
            place = int(place)
        except ValueError:
            print "",
        else:
            break
            #This will be executed only if no exception is raised
    if place == '.':
        import sys
        sys.exit()
    elif place > 9 or place < 1:
        place = 0
    return place
#Player 1 Marking Function Part 1 ends

#Player 1 Marking Function Part 2
def player12(place,grid,name1):
    if place == 0:
        while place==0:
            place == player11(name1,grid)
    grid[place] = markgrid('O',grid,place)
#Player 1 Marking Function Part 2 ends


#Player 2 Marking Function Part 1
def player21(name2,grid):
    while True:
        os.system('cls')
        viewgrid(grid)
        print name2, ", Please enter your choice from the grid above : ",
        place = raw_input()
        try:
            place = int(place)
        except ValueError:
            print "",
        else:
            break
            #This will be executed only if no exception is raised
    if place == '.':
        import sys
        sys.exit()
    elif place > 9 or place < 1:
        place = 0
    return place
#Player 2 Marking Function Part 1 ends

#Player 2 Marking Function Part 2
def player22(place,grid,name2):
    if place == 0:
        while place==0:
            place == player21(name2,grid)
    grid[place] = markgrid('X',grid,place)
#Player 2 Marking Function Part 2 ends



#Reset Grid Code starts here
def gridreset(grid):
    j = 0     
    for j in range(0,10):
        grid.append(j)
#Reset Grid Code ends here

#This is the main program, defined as a function itself
def playgame():
    print "\n\nUser 1 - Please Enter your name : ",
    name1 = raw_input()
    print "User 2 - Please Enter your name : ",
    name2 = raw_input()
    print "\n",name1,", your marking is O",
    print "\n",name2,", your marking is X"
    user1 = 'O'
    user2 = 'X'
    raw_input()
    grid = []
    gridreset(grid)
    def player1(name1):
        i = player11(name1,grid)
        if markgrid('O',grid,i) == 0:
            player1(name1)
        player12(i,grid,name1)
        i = checkwin(grid)
        print i
        if i==1 or i == -1:
            diswin(name1,grid)
        player2(name2)
        return grid
    def player2(name2):
        i = player21(name2,grid)
        if markgrid('X',grid,i) == 0:
            player2(name2)
        player22(i,grid,name2)
        i = checkwin(grid)
        if i==1 or i == -1:
            diswin(name2,grid)
        player1(name1)
        return grid
    player1(name1)
    player2(name2)
    return grid
#Main Program end

#Main Program Execution
grid = []

grid = playgame()
```

A problem I am facing now, is that in `player11` and `player12` The program is able to take input >9 or <1 and asks for the input again... But just after that when the correct input is provided... Nothing Happens... Any help is appreciated :)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up your assignment `=` and equality check `==`.  So you have lines:

```
if place == 0:
        while place==0:
            place == player11(name1,grid)
```

(similarly for the other played) and you need the third one to begin `place =` not `place ==`.

Comment: For this, you do not need to put the `if place == 0:`. The `while` statement, unlike the `do` statement in other languages (C++, Objective C), does not have to repeat even once. All you need is `while place == 0: place = player11(name1, grid)`

Comment: Agreed but, while unnecessary, it is not an error unlike the mixed up = and ==.  I specifically restricted the answer to pointing out the bug in the OP's code.

Comment: In my opinion, any chance to make a programmer more aware of certain extra steps can prove beneficial to him (or her) in the future. Better to help more than less!

Comment: I eventually got it ...
Just some tiredness which might have caused it :P
Thanks anyway :)